# Do you advise against using text files instead of database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, storage, forum

To make things short: I'm writing an anonymous forum software with PHP. I just feel like using a database is overkill and restrains my amateur skills. Do you advise against using text files instead of database?

Thanks.

Comment: using text file its not possible to maintain the relation between entities. So we need relational database. Hence you need relational database.

Comment: A text file is not ACID compliant. Thus you are going to have to develop your own transactional mechanisms on a text file. If you are a serious coder this will be much more work  than learning how to use a database. And also you be reinventing the wheel. Go for a database

Comment: I had completely forgotten about the whole relational thing. I'll use a database. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A database has advantages like some sanitation (no breaking of delimiters, newlines etc.) and less danger of access conflicts when multiple instances try to read from the table - and different from a file-based approach, writing conflicts are constrained to the record in question only.

Recommendation: use database

Answer (score 1):

To make things short: Yes. Strong advise against text files.